# app.post not working for any route other than root route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i was trying to make a calculator and a bmi calculator using express but when i try to post to the bmicalculator route, rather than the sending the response i have specifies under the bmicalculator route it sends the response of the roout route
i don't know what to do, please help?

```
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  var result = num1 + num2;
  res.send("The Result is:" + result);
});

app.get("/bmicalculator", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bmiCal.html");
});

app.post("/bmicalculator", function(req,res){
  var height= parseFloat(req.body.height);
  var weight = parseFloat(req.body.weight);
  var bmi = weight /(height *height);
  res.send("YOUR BMI IS " + bmi);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Sharing the form you posted makes it easier for us to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is all about route specificity.
When accessing `/bmicalculator`, any routes below `/` won't be matched as the first route `/` matches first. In fact, the first route `/` matches with all the routes.

```
app.get("/bmicalculator", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/bmiCal.html");
});

app.post("/bmicalculator", function(req,res){
  var height= parseFloat(req.body.height);
  var weight = parseFloat(req.body.weight);
  var bmi = weight /(height *height);
  res.send("YOUR BMI IS " + bmi);
});


app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);
  var result = num1 + num2;
  res.send("The Result is:" + result);
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```